# Balanced multi-criteria trees

Tags: data-structures, trees

We have an n-ary tree used for searching that we'd like to keep balanced.  It is currently mostly a B-tree without the balancing operations. The issue we have for implementing those is that each sub-tree has its own sorting criteria (chosen in a set of five, if that's important) and that the balancing algorithms we know don't work in that case.

Is there a known algorithm which work in that case?  Or for a variation, we would probably reduce the number of criteria -- but not to one! -- and ensure that all nodes at a given level are using the same criteria if that help to keep the tree balanced at a reasonable cost and avoid rebuilding the whole tree like we do in some cases.

Comment: I think you'll need to tell us more about what you mean by "that case", i.e., what do you mean by "sorting criteria" and why it conflicts with standard balancing algorithms.  Can you give us a bit more details?  Or an abstraction of what a sorting criterion is and how it affects standard balancing methods?

Comment: @D.W. I'll try to update the question tomorrow, but waiting for that you can think of a kd-tree at each level you split along a different dimension (excepted that we have something more like a B-tree than a binary tree and that our dimensions have just an ordering and not a metric -- that's why I've called them sorting criteria -- ; but that doesn't seem significant), the issue with balancing is the same, changing a node's parent will break invariants.